# How to define a table's Foreign Key in JPA without defining an extra field?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables and I want one table to have a foreign key constraint on the other.
However, I *DO NOT* want to define an extra data field in one or both of the classes because JPA will post-process each record doing a db call for each record. (This is slow and not scalable.)

Instead, I want to simply define the DDL that creates the foreign key constraint and let the constraint do it's job in the background when I try to insert into the constrained table.

Using JPA annotations, or configurations, how do I create the foreign key constraint *WITHOUT* resorting to extra data fields in the entity class.

##### Sample entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission_map")
@IdClass(UserPermissionMapId.class)
public class UserPermissionMap extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NonNull
    private String user_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "permissionId")// This should have a foreign key constraint on permission.id.
    @NonNull
    private String permissionId;
...


@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
public class Permission extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NonNull
    private String id;
...
```

### Update For clariety:

I want to do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission_map")
@IdClass(UserPermissionMapId.class)
public class UserPermissionMap extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NonNull
    private String user_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "permissionId")// This should have a foreign key constraint on permission.id.
    @ForeignKey(target = "permission.id") <<<<
    @NonNull
    private String permissionId;
...
```

or

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission_map")
@ForeignKey(field = "permissionId", target = "permission.id") <<<<
@IdClass(UserPermissionMapId.class)
public class UserPermissionMap extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NonNull
    private String user_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "permissionId")// This should have a foreign key constraint on permission.id.
    @NonNull
    private String permissionId;
...
```

Comment: A shared primary sounds could fit your need. However, I don't know if JPA does some magic behind the scenes which includes what you want to avoid - an additional field or join table.
Checkout https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one for the example with @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")

Comment: Re: my previous comment. The example on baeldung does actually set an additional field in the entity that holds the key that is referred to. So that is not a solution that fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example from the [javaee docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) could help you. I adapted the class names and attribute to fit yours:

```java
   //Example 2: One-to-one association that assumes both the source and target share the same primary key values. 

    @Entity
    public class UserPermissionMap {
        @Id Integer id;
    
        @OneToOne @MapsId
        Permission permission;
        ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Permission {
        @Id Integer id;
        ...
    }
```

It also states that it is not required to add a mapping on both sides, if it is unidirectional (which is also what you want, if I hear you correctly).

> It is not normally necessary to specify the associated target entity explicitly since it can usually be inferred from the type of the object being referenced

Comment: This is what I was trying to say I do not want. It's too slow and isn't scalable when querying because it makes a seperate DB call for every User Permission Map record.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this approach only half fulfills the requirerements. It doesn't add a new data field to either class but JPA makes separate DB calls. Can you elaborate why UserPermissionMap and Permission are separate classes? It sounds like you want to retrieve them in one single DB call.

Comment: You should use laziness : `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: @Omnibyte I'm not trying to get data. I'm trying to define a Foreign Key constraint.